# Cannot add content after PDF reaches certain size

Tags: javascript, pdf, html2canvas, jspdf

I made a recursive function for generate a PDF iterating some divs. When there's no more divs, I save the PDF. I'm using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to catpure the HTML code of each div into a canvas and [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) to put the canvas as an image and generate the PDF. This code works well, except when the PDF exceeds 8MB, it stops adding content:

I want to know if jsPDF have a limit in size when generating PDF's.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

appendDataToPDF(some_div, doc, 1); /* calling function below */

function appendDataToPDF(div, doc, top)
{
    html2canvas(div, {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 10, top, width, height);

            if(top > 200 /* some value to detect if limit of page reached */)
            {
                doc.addPage();
                top = 1;
            }
            else
                top += 40;

            div = div.nextSibling;

            if(div === null)
                doc.save('Test.pdf');
            else
                appendDataToPDF(div, doc, top);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any hard limits, other than resources available to your machine. Max I generated was only a 2.7MiB 21-page pdf file but I could only save this file on my machine. Displaying it directly in a new tab would cause FF and Chrome to crash, probably because the data: uri is too long, since smaller files work just fine.

FYI, you can actually call `doc.addHTML()` in the current version, which uses [*html2canvas* internally](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/v1.0.272/jspdf.plugin.addhtml.js#L15-L16):

```
function appendDataToPDF(div, doc, top, left) {
    doc.addHTML(div, top, left, {w: width, h: height}, function() {
        if(top > 200) {
            doc.addPage();
            top = 1;
        }
        else
            top += 40;

        div = div.nextSibling;

        if(div === null)
            doc.save('Test.pdf');
        else
            appendDataToPDF(div, doc, top, left);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the plugin too.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what the problem was (ironically, after adding the bounty). I don't know why, but I just  appended to the body the div I was converting to PDF, and it worked. Now converts to html all the content inside the div.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem. It seems that in order to produce the canvas (and therefore the PDF) from a DOM element, the DOM element has to be part of the rendered HTML document. I guess it needs to be part of the document to calculate all the dimensions.